# Cargar arraylist desde base de datos mysql y mostrarlo en un h:datatable utilizando managedbean

Tags: mysql, jsp

Necesito mostrar los datos de la tabla de base de datos mysql en xhtml. utilizando managedbean arraylist y h:dataTable. A continuación presento los codigos de las clases utilizadas:

Codigo de la Clase Uea

```
public class Uea {
    private Integer clave;
    private String nombre;
    private Integer trimestre;
    private String requisito;

    public Uea(Integer clave, String nombre, Integer trimestre, String requisito) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void setClave(int cla) {
        clave = cla;
    }
    public int getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nom) {
        nombre = nom;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setTrimestre(int tri) {
        trimestre = tri;
    }
    public int getTrimestre() {
        return trimestre;
    }
    
    public void setRequisito(String req) {
        requisito = req;
    }
    public String getRequisito() {
        return requisito;
    }
    
}
```

A continuación la Clase de conexion a BD

```
package Model;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.*;


public class ConectaBD {
    private Connection conexion = null;
    private String servidor = "localhost";
    private String database = "materiasingcomp";
    private String usuario = "root";
    private String password = "";
    private String url = "";
    
    public ConectaBD(){
        try{
            // Establece la conexion con la base de datos
        //    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        //    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/materiasingcomp";
        //    conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            url="jdbc:mysql://"+servidor+"/"+database;
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,password);
        }
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } 
    }
        
    public Connection getConexion(){
        return conexion; 
    }
    public Connection cerrarConexion(){
        try {
            conexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        conexion=null;
        return conexion;
    }
        
}
```

A continuación la clase para cargar el arraylist y mostrar los datos

```
package Model;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.*;       

public class GestorBD {
    private Connection conexion=null;
    private Statement stm = null;
    private ResultSet ueaResultSet;
    private Integer clave, trimestre;
    private String nombre, requisito;
    
    public ArrayList<Uea> leerUeas(){
        ArrayList<Uea> ueas = new ArrayList<Uea>();
        Uea ueaHallada;
        try {
            ConectaBD conectaBD = new ConectaBD();
            conexion = conectaBD.getConexion();
            stm = conexion.createStatement();
            ueaResultSet = stm.executeQuery("select * from ueas");
            if (!ueaResultSet.next()){
                System.out.println("No se encontraron registros");
                conexion.close();
                return null;
            } else {
                do {
                    clave = ueaResultSet.getInt("clave");
                    nombre = ueaResultSet.getString("nombre");
                    trimestre = ueaResultSet.getInt("trimestre");
                    requisito = ueaResultSet.getString("requiere");
                    ueaHallada = new Uea(clave,nombre,trimestre,requisito);
                    ueas.add(ueaHallada);  
                }while (ueaResultSet.next());
                conexion.close();
                return ueas;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la base de datos");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

A continuación el codigo del managedbean completo, con funciones de buscar, borrar entre otras.

```
Package Controller;

import Model.GestorBD;
import Model.Uea;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.*;
import javax.*;
import Model.*;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ControllerManagedBean {

    private Integer clave;
    private String nombre;
    private Integer trimestre;
    private String requisito;
    private final GestorBD gestorBD;
    
    private static ArrayList<Uea> ueasList;
    
    public ControllerManagedBean(){
        gestorBD = new GestorBD();
        ueasList = gestorBD.leerUeas();                                
    }
    
    public Integer getClave(){
        return clave;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;        
    }
    
    public Integer getTrimestre(){
        return trimestre;
    }
    
    public String getRequisito(){
        return requisito;        
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Uea> getUeasList(){
        return ueasList;
    }
    
    public void pedirDatosUEA_aAgregar() {
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("agregar_UEA.xhtml");
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
    }
    
    public void guardarUEA() {
        Uea ueaNueva = new Uea(clave,nombre,trimestre,requisito);
        if (gestorBD.guardarUea(ueaNueva)) {
            try {
                ueasList = gestorBD.leerUeas();
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
                
            }    
        }
    }
    
    public void pedirDatosUEA_aBorrar(){
        try{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("borrar_UEA.xhml");
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public void borrarUEA(){
        Uea ueaABorrar = new Uea(clave,nombre,trimestre,requisito);
        if (gestorBD.borrarUea(ueaABorrar)){
            try{
                ueasList = gestorBD.leerUeas();
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
            }catch (IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    public void pedirDatosUEA_aLocalizar(){
        try{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("localizar_UEA.xhml");
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void localizarUEA(){
        if (gestorBD.localizaUEA(clave,nombre)){
            try{
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("modificar_UEA.xhtml");
            } catch (IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);    
            }
        }else 
            try {
                ueasList = gestorBD.leerUeas();
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("error.xhtml");
            }catch (IOException ex){
                Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
    public void modificarUEA(){
        Uea uea_a_Cambiar = new Uea(clave,nombre,trimestre,requisito);
        if (gestorBD.modificarUea(uea_a_Cambiar)){
            try{
                ueasList = gestorBD.leerUeas();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControllerManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y finalmente el codigo del index.xhtml que contiene la llamada al managedbean para cargar los datos en una tabla, ademas de algunos botones propios del CRUD (agregar,modificar,borrar)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>UEA Ing Comp</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h2 style="color: blue;">Lista de UEA en Ingeniería en Computación</h2>
        <h:form>        
            <h:dataTable value ="#{ControllerManagedBean.ueasList}" var="uea" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Clave</f:facet>
                    #{uea.clave}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Nombre</f:facet>
                    #{uea.nombre}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Trimestre</f:facet>
                    #{uea.trimestre}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Requisito</f:facet>
                    #{uea.requisito}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <h:commandButton value="Agregar UEA" type="submit" 
                                action="#{ControllerManagedBean.pedirDatosUEA_aAgregar()}"/>
            <span></span>
            <h:commandButton value="Borrar UEA" type="submit" 
                                action="#{ControllerManagedBean.pedirDatosUEA_aBorrar()}"/> 
            <span></span>  
            <h:commandButton value="Modificar UEA" type="submit" 
                                 action="#{ControllerManagedBean.pedirDatosUEA_aLocalizar()}"/>
            <span></span>  
        -->
        </h:form>      
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Al ejecutar todo esto no me muestra ni la tabla ni los botones, solo el encabezado del index.

Me gustaría puedan ayudarme por favor